# how to make a swf countdown to show in mobile and tablets?

Tags: php, flash

i hane a flash countdown file and its doesnt show in iphons,ipads and internet exlporers.
How can i fix it? Can i show html if some of them devices are request to view it?

```
<td align=\"center\">
          <span class=\"deal_big_title\" style=\"font-size:10px\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Days / Hours / Min / Sec</span>
          <div name=\"flashcontent".$i."\" style=\"text-align:center\" id=\"flashcontent".$i."\" align=\"center\"></div>
          <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var so = new SWFObject(\"light.html\", \"source\", \"180\", \"34\", \"9\", \"#FFFFFF\");
            so.addVariable('configPath', '".$Details['hm_end'][2]."-".$Details['hm_end'][1]."-".$Details['hm_end'][0]."-".$Details['wra_end'][0]."-".$Details['wra_end'][1]."-00-time.php');
            so.addParam('wmode', 'transparent');
            so.write(\"flashcontent".$i."\");
          </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not support Flash. If it's a simple counter, consider getting an HTML version as it would be easy to do in JavaScript.

Comment: i need someone to do it for me